# isKindOfClass does not work as expected IOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

The code below, returns "YES" on IOS 5.0, 6.0, 6.1 etc. but returns "NO" on IOS 7.0.
Dou you have an idea about that?
Is it an IOS 7.0 bug? 
Thanks a lot..

```
[view isKindOfClass:[SimpleLabel class]]
```

PS: "SimpleLabel" is a class inherited from UILabel.

----UPDATE----

Sorry for unclear question. :(
I use the code above in a `UITableViewCell` class, and add `SimpleLabel` as below;

```
 [self addSubview:label];
```

I override `layoutSubviews` function, loop in `self.subviews`, but `[view class]` always returns `UITableViewCellScrollView`.

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
[super layoutSubviews];
for (UIView*view in self.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[SimpleLabel class]]) {
        SimpleLabel*label = (SimpleLabel*)view;
```

Comment: Be aware that iOS7 and Xcode 5 are still covered by a NDA, which restricts you from talking about it outside of the official Apple Developers Forum.

Comment: I'm betting that your 'view' is nil

Comment: iOS7 is under NDA. You should post any question related to iOS7 in Apple Forums.

Comment: Please add the output of `NSLog(@"%@", view);` to your question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about iOS 7 which is under NDA.

Comment: Even I have tried for class which is inherited from NSObject. Which is working in Xcode-DP2.

Comment: For anyone who wishes to down or close vote due to NDA, please see: [Should moderators enforce NDAs for software vendors?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94465) and related questions. It is not SO's policy, responsibility, or concern to enforce or police NDAs between other parties. It is **not off topic** to ask about subjects which may be covered by a confidentiality agreement of any kind.

Comment: The obvious follow-up is what does `[view class]` return?

Comment: @JoshCaswell But it is off-topic as far as the fact that it is beta and subject to change before release.  Say that we spend a lot of time answering this question, and then a bug fix is shipped in the final version.  Then what good has this question done for the community?  It will have been relevant to only a small period in time, and other users might find this question later after the official release and start filing false bug reports because of it.  That's how I feel anyway.  I will still remind the user about their NDA though.

Comment: Beta software isn't off-topic, either, @borrrden: [Are questions about beta software ok for Stack Exchange?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132275) It can be cleaned up _later_ if it becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Hi all, sorry for unclear question, i have an update.

Comment: @seytan: you should do the `NSLog(@"%@", [view class])` that was mentioned previously and add it to your answer.

Comment: @NicholasSmith yeah i've already written it above on my question. "[view class] always returns UITableViewCellScrollView."

Comment: I haven't looked at Apple's iOS NDA for some time because I'm not currently subscribed to the iOS developer program, but it's entirely possible that those people stating that this question violates the iOS7 NDA might be violating the iOS7 NDA.  NDAs often have a clause which prevents you from discussing what the NDA covers :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UITableViewCell`'s view hierarchy changed slightly in iOS 7

In iOS <= 6 the hierarchy looks like

```
<UITableViewCell>
   | <UITableViewCellContentView>
   |    | <UILabel>
```

whereas in iOS 7 it's like

```
<UITableViewCell>
   | <UITableViewCellScrollView>
   |    | <UIButton>
   |    |    | <UIImageView>
   |    | <UITableViewCellContentView>
   |    |    | <UILabel>
```

(source: http://www.curiousfind.com/blog/646)

When you add a subview it is inserted in the `UITableViewCellContentView` which is one level deeper than where you are looking for.

`isKindOfClass:` works properly, the issues is that you are going through the wrong set of subviews.

By the way this is a splendid example of why you should never rely on internal view hierarchies: Apple can change them at any time.

Comment: Thanks Gabriele, i'll check it out and give feedback to you.